# Auto Generate Custom Text Message for Page Break

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, tcolorbox

I created a new environment that creates a box around text. I used `tcolorbox`. Additionally, since I wanted to break from page to page, I added 'breakable'. However, what I want it to do is to break the box from page to page, but also automatically write a message, for example, "theorem x cont.", anytime there are breaks in the page. I want to write this message inside the box. How can I do this?

Edit: Basically, I want to do this: [Breaking a theorem between pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72829/breaking-a-theorem-between-pages?rq=1), but not using mdframed and inside my box which contains other text.

I want to do something like this: [image] The italicized text. Blue line represents page break.

My code thus far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{cframed}
  {\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=gray!6]}
  {\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{cframed}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{cframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The picture is a good hint. Yet a MWE is to follow: 1) to see your attempts and 2) to just have a starting point. Help your helpers! :)

Comment: @Ruben Edited it

Comment: the `title after break`could help you : page 307 of the `tcolorbox` documentation

Comment: @flav Is there a way to get the number. For example, thm 1 cont.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newcounter{theoInt}
\newcommand\numtheo{\stepcounter{theoInt}\arabic{theoInt}}

\newenvironment{cframed}
  {\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,%
      colback=gray!6,titlerule=0pt,
      title after break=\emph{Theorem \numtheo{} cont.},
      colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black]}
  {\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{cframed}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{cframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of X, I want it to show the number of the theorem

Comment: Also, is there a way to get rid of that line under Theorem X cont.?

Comment: you can use a counter

Comment: What about getting rid of the line?

Comment: set ,titlerule=0pt,

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=10cm]{geometry}%for testing purposes
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  notefont=\mdseries,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  preheadhook={\begin{tcolorbox}[
    breakable, titlerule=\z@, colbacktitle=gray!6, colback=gray!6, coltitle=black,
    title after break={\itshape\thmt@thmname~\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname~(cont.)}]},
  prefoothook=\end{tcolorbox}
]{framedthm}
\makeatother
\declaretheorem[style=framedthm,numbered=yes]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of that formatting for Theorem 1 (cont.)?

Comment: @user102690, yes. I updated the answer.